# I'm new to linear Algebra and can not find any information on how to solve the following question

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the volume of a tetrahedron whose vertices are (-2, -4, -1), (5, -5, 0), (0, 4, 0), and (-7, 5, 3). I can not find how to use vertices instead of plotting points. Are they the same function?

Comment: the following link has a description of how to find the volume using the determinant of a matrix http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html

Comment: You could do it by find one of the sides plan and the height of the 4th point. the volume will be as I assume you know a 1/3 of the triangle on the plan multiplied by the height.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$, the volume of the tetrahedron is $1/6$ of the volume of the parallelepiped defined by them, which is the determinant of $[p_1-p_0, p_2-p_0, p_3-p_0]$.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of a tetrahedron (or any other pyramid / cone) is:
$$\dfrac13 \times \text{area of 'base'} \times \text{perpendicular height}.$$

You can use your vertices to make vectors for the sides of the tetrahedron.

**Hint for area of 'base'**: If you've learned about the cross product, the *magnitude* of $\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}$, usually written something like $\left\|\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}\right\|$, is the area of the parallelogram have $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as sides. Can you think of a way to turn this into the area of the *triangle* with $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as sides?

**Hint for perpendicular height**: The dot product can be used to find the 'amount' of one vector in the direction of another vector. If vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the sides of the 'base' face on your tetrahedron, and vector $\mathbf{C}$ is one of the sides coming from the base up to the 'top', then the height of the tetrahedron perpendicular to the 'base' is the amount of vector $\mathbf{C}$ in the direction perpendicular to the base. Read up in your notes / textbook on the dot product and projections.

Comment: Thank you for the help I will look into your suggestions about dot product!